# Automatically adjust the height of MDCard when the text of the label is long

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to automatically adjust the height of a MDCard when a Label of text if long. Here is the code below. Thanks people!

.kv file

:
adaptive_height: True
size_hint: 1, None
#size_hint_y: None
height: self.minimum_height
orientation: 'vertical'
padding: "8dp"

```
OneLineAvatarListItem:
    text: "Message"
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: 'email'
MDCard:
    id: card1
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "280dp", "180dp"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'trash-can'
        on_release: app.remove(root)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9}

    MDLabel:
        text: root.label_var1
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```